# How do i populate a div in parent html/php from an ajax loaded child php

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, html, parent

Let's say i have an index.php that has html in it that looks like this:

```
<div id="navigation">
  <ul>
     <li id="registerLink"><a href="#">Register</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="mainContent">
</div>
```

and i have jquery that does this:

```
$('#registerLink').click(function() {
   $('#mainContent').load("register.php");
});
```

With this, i smoothly load my form which is coded in the register.php file into the mainContent div. Now, when i fill in the form and post it using ajax which is coded in the register.php file, i want the results to display using jquery ajax in the mainContent div which is in the original index.php file.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#mainContent form').submit(function(){
  var form = $(this);

  $.post(form.attr('action'), form.serialize(), function(result){
    $('#mainContent').html(result);
  });

  return false;
});
```

this code must be run as callback in your .load(..., [right here] )

Comment: Brilliant. Seems so simple. Just a couple of clarifications. 1. This code would be all part of the callback function of the load in the index.php. Is this because if i just had it as part of the document.ready it would not recognize because register.php has not been loaded yet? 2. what does return false mean? Thanks.

Comment: 1. yes, exactly. Or you can use .delegate() to catch all forms with specific class or id. 2. return false prevents native form submission.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the [jQuery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) for this.